# Using a matrix to position objects in 3D space

Tags: 3d, rotation, position, matrix-transform

When using a 3D matrix transformation, is it possible to use only a matrix for each object to both position, rotate and scale the object? Would I also need to maintain a separate set of location information in order to, for example, perform operations like "rotate around arbitrary point"?

I ask because I can't quite work out how to (specifically...) rotate around an arbitrary point, though this relates to general management of an object's spacial information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a 4x4 matrix. A 3x3 matrix in 3D space only describes *linear* transformations, which do not include positioning (translation).

See here for more details on implementation:
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/matrix4x4/. Plenty more on Google.

E.g. for rotation around an arbitrary point **P**, construct the following matrices:

- **A**: translation by *minus* **P**
- **B**: your rotation (Euler angles or whatever)
- **C**: translation by *plus* **P**

The final matrix you want is **CBA** (in that order, assuming right-multiplication with vectors)